# Remounting /home from other partition on new install without copying

Tags: mount, users, home, migration

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 and have created a new smaller disk with Mint 18. Now my plan is to mount the old partition from `/mountpoint/oldroot/home/` into `/home` on the new system. So I create all 3 users with same user name and password as on the old system and then edit `/etc/fstab`, right?

Questions:

- I need to make sure that the numerical uid and gid match, how do I do that?
- Is there any other thing to watch out for?

Ideally, I'd like to avoid running `chown` on the old home, because I'd like to use the two systems in parallel until I'm confident the transition was successful. But I'm a bit worried that I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adjusting the GID and UID of the new install to those of the old installation using `usermod -u <old-uid> <login>` and `groupmod -g <old-gid> <login>` and made sure that the home directories are named the same on the new as on the old system. To change to the new home directories, I edited the fstab to mount them in `/home`, then renamed the default user directories `mv /home/login /home/login_old` and made empty directories `mkdir /home/login` as mount points used in the fstab file. After that, I immediately rebooted.

It worked fine and without errors, as Mint 17.3 and 18 were sufficiently similar.

I wouldn't recommend this in general for migrating from one distro to another or if the desktop environment is changed, because the old settings a user's home directory might cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `usermod` command to change a users credentials:

UID or GID:

```
usermod -u NEW_UID USERNAME
usermod -g NEW_GID USERNAME
```

So you can adopt the values of your old system.

Home directory location (only if incomplete moving of /home ...)

```
usermod -d /path/to/new/home/dir USERNAME
```

For also moving the contents of the current home dir to the new location, use the `-m` option.

Alternatively you might also just move the old `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` files to the new system and skip the resetting of UID an GID.

One problem I see, might be if the two systems use the same names for some config files and thus produce errors.